# Is it possible to choose what should be the field to be return in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am wondering if there is a way that i can choose what field should be included in the result of dynamodb query or scan. I try to use AttributesToGet

```
def filter_ga_account_by_email(self, email):
    response = Table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr('client_email').eq(email),
        AttributesToGet=['id'],
    )

    return response['Items']
```

and now i have this error : `ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Can not use both expression and non-expression parameters in the same request: Non-expression parameters: {AttributesToGet} Expression parameters: {FilterExpression}`

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to add the projectionExpression parameter and specify the attributes that you want to return in a array of strings, a working example:

```
    const getProducts = (user) => {
                    var params = {
                        TableName: process.env.PRODUCTS,
                        ScanIndexForward: false,
                        KeyConditionExpression: 'user = :hkey',
                        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                            ':hkey': user,
                        },
                        Limit: 200,
                        ProjectionExpression: ['internal_type', 'requested_at']
                };
     return dynamoClient.query(params).promise();
}
```

Comment: ProjectionExpression should be of type string, not array of strings

Answer (score 2):

sure,

you can use 'AttributesToGet':

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

response = client.get_item(TableName='tbl_name', Key={'client_email':{'N':str(email)}}, AttributesToGet=['id'])
```

but please note:

> This is a legacy parameter, for backward compatibility. New
>   applications should use ProjectionExpression instead. Do not combine
>   legacy parameters and expression parameters in a single call;
>   otherwise, DynamoDB will return a ValidationException exception. This
>   parameter allows you to retrieve attributes of type List or Map;
>   however, it cannot retrieve individual elements within a List or a
>   Map.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#API_Query_RequestSyntax

Comment: i got this error `ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Can not use both expression and non-expression parameters in the same request: Non-expression parameters: {AttributesToGet} Expression parameters: {FilterExpression}
` btw i am suing scan. I will update my code too.

Comment: i edited my answer.. (Do not combine legacy parameters and expression parameters in a single call; otherwise, DynamoDB will return a ValidationException exception)

Comment: Error again `TypeError: object.__new__(thread.lock) is not safe, use thread.lock.__new__()` I am a newbie also in python.

Comment: this error is not related to dynamodb/boto. try first to fetch records in a simple way.

Comment: using `scan` and `FilterExpressions` gives me the correct result but using `AttributesToGet` gives me the error.

Comment: This answer is valid for the "legacy" keyword arguments. See below for more current keyword argument set with current keyword arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The [boto3 dynamodb docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.query) note that you are not able to combine the "legacy" parts of the API (including the *Select* and *AttributeToGet* keywords arguments) with the newer API keyword arguments including *KeyConditionExpression* and *ProjectionExpression*). This is why you are getting the ValidationError. The correct way to only query certain attributes is using the `ProjectionExpression` keyword argument.

If you want to query for specific attributes only (while using the "new" keyword argument set), you can use the below code:

```py
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

table = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name='us-east-2').Table(<table_name>

def filter_ga_account_by_email(self, email):
    response = table.scan(
        IndexName='client_email', # Include if client_email is an indexed field
        FilterExpression=Attr('client_email').eq(email), # Include if client_email is a non-indexed field
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('client_email').eq(email), # Include if client_email is an indexed field
        ProjectionExpression="id", # Comma-separated list of desired attributes, e.g., "id,client_id
    )

    return response['Items']
```

In response to your question about getting specific attributes, the `ProjectionExpression` is the best way to do this.