# Using both AttributesToGet and KeyConditionExpression with boto3 and dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am interested in returning all records with a given partition key value (i.e., u_type = "prospect"). But I only want to return specific attributes from each of those records.
I have scraped together the following snippet from boto docs & Stack answers:

```
resp = table.query(
        Select='SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES',
        AttributesToGet=[
            'u_type','ID','action','status','first_name','last_name'
        ],
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('u_type').eq("prospect")
        )
```

When running this I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: 
Can not use both expression and non-expression parameters in the same request: 
Non-expression parameters: {AttributesToGet} 
Expression parameters: {KeyConditionExpression}
```

Additionally, I have experimented with using ProjectionExpression with the following implementation:

```
resp = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression= 'u_type = :hkey',
        ExpressionAttributeValues= {
            ':hkey': "prospect",
        },
        Limit= 200,
        ProjectionExpression= ['u_type','ID','action','status','first_name','last_name']
        )
```

*Note that this was adjusted from [another stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876836/is-it-possible-to-choose-what-should-be-the-field-to-be-return-in-dynamodb) written for node.*

When using this ProjectionExpression implementation I face the following error:

```
Invalid type for parameter ProjectionExpression, value: 
['u_type', 'ID', 'action', 'status', 'first_name', 'last_name'], type: <class 'list'>, 
valid types: <class 'str'>
```

I am unsure if my approach or description is unclear, but in essence I would like to do the following SQL equivalent using boto3 and dynamo:

```
SELECT u_type,ID,action,status,first_name,last_name
FROM table
WHERE u_type LIKE 'prospect';
```

*Note: Partition key: u_type, Sort key: ID*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AttributesToGet` is a legacy parameter, and [the documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.query) suggests using the newer `ProjectionExpression` instead. The documentation also says that `ProjectionExpression` is a string, not a list. It may be a list in the NodeJS SDK, in the answer you linked to, but in Python the documentation says it must be a string. So I would try this:

```
resp = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression= 'u_type = :hkey',
        ExpressionAttributeValues= {
            ':hkey': "prospect",
        },
        Limit= 200,
        ProjectionExpression='u_type,ID,action,status,first_name,last_name'
        )
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Mark, appreciate the time!